# bath faucet dripping and moving!

Tags: bathroom, shower, faucet, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures

My shower lower faucet has been dripping for a few months. Last month I tried to change the cartridge, but it didn't work.   I then found it didn't drip after I tightened the faucet clockwise but now it is dripping again.

I found both the faucet and the control knob are moving a little bit towards the left day by day. You can see the gaps which are breaking the caulk.

**How can I stop this?**  *I worry it may be leaking inside*.

[image]

Updated 4/17/2021
Finally I fixed it. Not cartridge issue, it was because there are whitewater residues with brass green rust, they introduced space when switch is turned on. I removed those dirties, then it didn’t drip now.

Next is to fix movement of shower hardware, wall doesn’t move, the hardware does

Comment: If it were leaking in the wall there is a good chance you will see it in the ceiling of the room below. There is probably no connection between the dripping faucet and the shift in the faucet and control on the tile wall. Sometimes the pipe brace on the copper in the wall loosens and just turning the control knob on and off can move it. Especially if you torqued the faucet another turn. If it's still dripping you need to replace the cartridge in the control valve.

Comment: I think you have two separate issues - dripping faucet, and movement of the shower wall (both hardware are moving toward left). For the latter, you should try to maintain the humidity in the bathroom with ventilation device, such as exhaust fan, or dehumidifier.

Comment: It will stop migrating when it reaches its summer breading grounds.

Comment: @r13  It sounds as if you saying the Wall is  moving while the valve is staying put? Surly that is unlikely.

Comment: @Alaska Man I guess the wall is shifting due to repetitive expansion and shrinking. The piping shouldn't be moving unless an external force is applied to it. What do you think?